# How can I open the dial pad during a call using adb?

Tags: android, shell, adb

When I need to see my doctor I have to:

1. Call to 666666666
2. Wait 5 seconds
3. Press 1
4. Wait 5 seconds
5. Press 20*30*1990
6. Wait 5 secondos
7. Press 1

So I want to automatizate all this steps

I know that I can fire the call doing:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:666666666
```

and I can simulate a input by:

```
sleep 5
adb shell input text "1"
sleep 5
adb shell input text "20*30*1990"
sleep 5
adb shell input text "1"
```

but It can't work if I don't open de dial pad after `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:666666666` and before `adb shell input text "1"`

So my question is: How can I open the dial pad during a call using adb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the coordinates of the dial's pad button and then simulate a press by sending `input tap x y`.
If your automation will be used on multiple devices from different types, I would advise you to write a simple python script that uses [uiautomator](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator) to do that task.